# Jenkins publish over SSH giving an error when I try to save new credentials

Tags: java, plugins, jenkins, ssh, devops

I am using Jenkins with publish over ssh plug-in. I have been able to do this successfully for many of my projects.  I currently have 12 different server configurations and I will need to keep adding more.

But when I am trying to add a new configuration for server credentials and I get the error below.  I am able to test the connection successfully.  I believe that there might be a limit to the number of credentials that can be added to the plug in.

[image: Adding In Credentials]

I have done some researching online but I cannot find much info on this problem. I am more or less lost with java debugging.  I am at a blocker due to not being able to setup the automated jobs for this project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated: even in just guiding me through some of the debugging process.

Thanks so much for your time!

Here is the error message I received:

---

A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.

```
Stack trace

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.model.Descriptor.getId(Descriptor.java:323)
at hudson.model.Descriptor.getConfigFile(Descriptor.java:797)
at com.google.jenkins.plugins.googlecontainerregistryauth.GoogleContainerRegistryCredential$DescriptorImpl.deleteConfigFile(GoogleContainerRegistryCredential.java:252)
at com.google.jenkins.plugins.googlecontainerregistryauth.GoogleContainerRegistryCredentialGlobalConfig.configure(GoogleContainerRegistryCredentialGlobalConfig.java:63)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.configureDescriptor(Jenkins.java:2956)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:2919)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
... 61 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests that this is caused by [an issue that was fixed](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31459) in the Google Container Registry Auth plugin.

Try upgrading to version 0.3 of that plugin, which contains the fix.

Comment: Thanks - upgrading the plugins did actually work.  Thanks for the help!